# Do we need geo routing if we add href-lang tag

Tags: node.js, seo

We need to deploy 2 websites :

`https://in.example.org` (Server in India)

`https://usa.example.org`  (Server in the USA)

we will be defining the `href-lang` tag for both websites in the Sitemap.xml

However, I am not sure if I need geo routing when people in the USA search for "example.org"

We want that when users in `USA` search for `example.org` - they should head to the USA website `https://usa.example.org`
whereas any user in the rest of the world search for `example.org` should head to the India website `https://in.example.org`

Comment: Geo-routing isn't just for localization though....

Answer (score 1):

href-lang tag should work. However there is a catch.

Referring to [this](https://help.dragonmetrics.com/en/articles/5226640-redirecting-hreflang-link)

> For each URL follow the redirect of hreflang URL to see what the final destination URL is. If this final URL represents the correct language/region for this hreflang tag, replace the hreflang URL of this tag with this final URL. If the final destination URL is not the correct URL for this language/region, find the best URL for this one to replace it or remove the tag completely. In either case, whichever URL you choose for this hreflang tag, ensure you create a reciprocal hreflang tag on this page as well.

Comment: so no need for geo location ? If person in USA searches for example.org Google will show https://usa.example.org first ? 

Will this work for Bing as well?

Comment: Yes. This will work. Also check this [link](https://developers.google.com/search/docs/advanced/crawling/localized-versions?visit_id=637980560977315017-4035376997&rd=1)

Comment: link only answer